# Kendo: MVC4 ComboBox restrict edit of contents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Using the following I have a ComboxBox bound to a Model.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.AppUserStatus)
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .BindTo(@ViewBag.StatusList)
       )
```

How do I prevent the text from being edited, but allow it to be picked as normal?

Comment: Why not use a DropDownList instead? http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent that. This is one of the features of a combobox - to allow custom values. Use a dropdownlist instead as suggested in the comments.